# Twitter API Error 32 Could not authenticate you

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

Trying to use twitter API to load my timeline on my website, but i'm getting the error `(code:32, message:Could not authenticate you)`.
But i can't seem to see the error in my code, please help my code is below, thanks.

Code:

```
$tw_arr = ["user_id" => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
            "screen_name" => xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
            'consumer_key' => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
            'consumer_secret' => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
            'oauth_access_token' => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
            'oauth_access_token_secret' => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx];

$tw_connection = new TwitterOAuth($tw_arr["consumer_key"],$tw_arr["consumer_secret"],$tw_arr["oauth_access_token"], $tw_arr["oauth_access_token_secret"]);

$tw_connection->host = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/';

$userTwTimeline = $tw_connection->get('statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id='.$tw_arr['user_id'].'&count=5&exclude_replies=true');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the SSL certificate?

I think that's the issue